# How to access files in the resources directories from scala source using sbt layout

Tags: java, scala, sbt

I am having issues using sbt and scala accessing files in different directories from scala code. I have the typical sbt directory layout shown below.

```
main
 |- build.sbt
 |- project/
 |- src/
     |- main/
         |- scala/
         |- resources/
               |- board
     |- test/
         |- scala/
 |- target/
     |- scala-2-11/
         |- classes
              |- board/
              |- com/
                  |- tgm
                      |- frpoject
```

Now in my code in the src/main/scala directory I have code that needs to access images in the resources/board directory. So executing it from the sbt console I thought it would be running from the classes directory under target so in my code I added it as so.

```
val white_b = "../../../board/ew.gif"
```

that didn't work so then I tried it from the source directory as so.

```
val white_b = "../resources/board/ew.gif"
```

I am trying to load the image with

```
val wb  = ImageIO.read(new File(this.white_b))
```

I keep getting the error

```
[error] (run-main-10) javax.imageio.IIOException: Can't read input file!
javax.imageio.IIOException: Can't read input file!
   at javax.imageio.ImageIO.read(ImageIO.java:1301)
```

Any help to what I am missing is appreciated. Thanks! :\

**EDIT:**

Apparently you have to access it this way if using sbt console

```
val white_b = "target/scala-2.11/classes/board/ew.gif"
```

So will this mess up the code once a jar is created, am I using resources wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this

```
val wb = ImageIO.read(classOf[YourClassHere].getResourceAsStream("/board/ew.gif"))
```

Just replace the name of your class in place of `YourClassHere`.

In sbt project layout, src/main/resources is on the root of the classpath. You can use the absolute path of your gif files from the root of the classpath (If src/main/resources is at the root, the absolute path of gif file is "/board/ew.gif").

What you were trying were relative paths, they are always with reference to a working directory for your program.